# ¿Qué es "ancilar"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, significado, adjetivos

Leo en un artículo de Mario Vargas Llosa:

> Defender el derecho de la mujer de decidir cuántos hijos quiere (y puede) tener es fundamental para garantizar la igualdad de géneros, y dar a las mujeres la independencia y los recursos de organizar su vida de acuerdo a su propio criterio, sin verse obligada por las circunstancias, como ha ocurrido y sigue ocurriendo todavía en gran parte del mundo, a ser sólo **un ser ancilar**, destinado a la procreación y al cuidado de la progenie.
>
> <sub>[¿Defensa de la vida?](https://elpais.com/elpais/2018/08/17/opinion/1534520449_086262.html), Mario Vargas Llosa. 19 agosto de 2018</sub>

Como nunca había oído *ancilar*, me fui al DLE en busca de respuestas:

> [**ancilar**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=2XsrTk3)
>   `Del lat. ancillāris.`
>
> 1. adj. Referente a la **ancila**. U. t. en sent. fig.
>
> > [**ancila**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=2XsgTaS)
> >     `Del lat. ancilla.`
> >
> > 1. f. p. us. Sierva, esclava, criada.

La definición no aclara mucho, pero entre esto y el contexto creo fácil entender que con lo de *un ser ancilar* se refiere a que la mujer sea una persona-objeto, alguien a merced de la voluntad de los otros.

Precisamente en la entrada [*Ancilar*](http://cuidaesalengua.blogspot.com/2007/05/ancilar.html) del blog *¡Cuida esa lengua!*<sup>1</sup> hablan de ella, compartiendo mi sorpresa ante el descubrimiento:

> El sustantivo no parece tener muchas aplicaciones hoy en día, cuando no hay esclavas y las criadas, si las hay, reciben otros nombres, pero el adjetivo "ancilar" me parece una bonita forma de decir "auxiliar" o "subordinado". Según [he visto en Google](http://www.google.es/search?hl=es&q=ancilar&btnG=Buscar%20con%20Google&meta=), es el uso que le dan los pocos que introducen la palabra en sus escritos. Hay veces en las que puede venir bien darle el cariz de esclavitud a una relación de subordinación, como al hablar de los anuncios que deberían someterse al programa televisivo (y no tener la misma duración).
>
> Con la excepción de esta breve búsqueda en Google, nunca había visto la palabra castellana en su hábitat natural. La he descubierto a través del inglés [ancillary](http://dictionary.reference.com/search?q=ancillary), que viene a tener el mismo significado pero que además parece poder usarse también como sustantivo, para referirse por ejemplo a los cachivaches que se usan como apoyo en una clase, como un proyector o una presentación PowerPoint.

Sin embargo, sigo con la duda: ¿dónde y con qué frecuencia se usa? ¿Se utiliza más por ejemplo en Perú, que es el país de origen de Vargas Llosa?

<sup>1</sup> Parece que después de un par de migraciones, ahora ese blog está en [Al sur de la frontera](http://www.alsurdelafrontera.es/).

Comment: Jamás la había leído o escuchado, medio adiviné su sentido por asociación con la palabra inglesa. Soy de Argentina.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Ancilar* significa subordinado, siervo. Es un término culto, como también lo es su homólogo inglés, *ancillary*. Ambos están tomados directamente del latín, como cultismo (no a través de la evolución natural). Es igualmente infrecuente en todos los países de habla hispana, es decir, no es un peruanismo.

La usamos con cierta frecuencia en filosofía, física y matemáticas para denotar objetos auxiliares, "anclados", dependientes de un objeto principal, pero en muchos casos como calco del inglés.

Comment: Ancillary is not "culto"; it's "bureaucratese", or technical. And it has nothing to do with ancilar in Spanish used in a literary manner.

Comment: "Culto" is a techical linguistic term, equivalent to "learned" or "semi-learned" borrowing in English, refering.to its origin.

Answer (score 3):

Se utiliza a nivel intelectual y académico para significar una excesiva dependencia de una persona, institución o campo teórico distinto, esto último mucho en filosofía.

Por ejemplo, podemos decir que la filosofía no debe ser *ancilar* de la teología y ni siquiera de la ciencia, sino que debe ser libre en sus reflexiones.

Yo soy de Madrid (España) y me consta que este es un uso culto -pero nada superfluo sino plenamente justificado- en toda el área del español o castellano.

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias José Luis por tu aportación y bienvenido a [spanish.se].